# Does lldb automatically terminate an infinite loop?

Tags: lldb

I wrote an infinite loop like the following

```
for (size_t i = words-1; i >= 0; --i) {
    ... data[i] ...
}
```

and it would also access OOB memory. The executable crashes with a coredump. Using gdb with the coredump shows me it crashes when i is a huge number.

However, lldb can successfully run the same executable w/o any crash... Did LLDB 'interpret' the code and fix the issue for me?

Comment: Note it's [impossible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) for a debugger (or any machine code) to detect a generic infinite loop (of course you can make rules for the most obvious ones).

Answer (score 0):

No, that would be a horrible thing for a debugger to do!  Debuggers in general, and lldb in particular, try hard to run your program as closely as possible to how it runs normally.   There are a couple of intrusive jobs the debugger has to do when running "flat out" - e.g. it has to pause when there are shared library loads to read in the new libraries, and the debugger gets first crack at signals sent to the program.  So particularly in multi-threaded programs the debugger might perturb timings.  But it should never change the instruction flow of code in your program.

If you can make up a test case showing a crash when run in command line but not in lldb, please file a bug with the lldb bug tracker:

https://bugs.llvm.org

and include the example.